# next.js compression error in Plesk, node.js options

Tags: node.js, reactjs, .net, .net-core, next.js

I have a server.js file in the Plesk panel and when I build the node js app, it shows an error. Please help me if you have any experience in this filed :

```
(node:18208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\aylimenu.com\httpdocs\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:98
    compression = this.nextConfig.compress && this.nextConfig.target === "server" ? (0, _compression).default() : undefined;
                ^
```

Comment: Can you show us your `next.config.js` file?

Comment: This is the next.config.js : ```const withImages = require("next-images");
module.exports = withImages({
    reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: true,
    images: {
        domains: ["api.aylimenu.com"],
        disableStaticImages: true,
    },
    
});```