# nodeJS compression = this.nextConfig.compress error

Tags: node.js, next.js, syntax-error, cpanel

i have an error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: /home/uri/10/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:110
    compression = this.nextConfig.compress && this.nextConfig.target === "server" ? (0, _compression).default() : undefined;
                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Timeout.getServerImpl [as _onTimeout] (/home/uri/10/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:59:71)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
(node:973058) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:973058) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
error - Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
(node:973058) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Not supported
    at Object.loadConfig [as default] (/home/uri/10/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/config.js:68:78)
(node:973058) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
```

the only solution was [this but it dosen't provide a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162080/next-js-compression-error-in-plesk-node-js-options)

when trying to deploy a next js app in cPanel hosted with nodeJS

any help would be appreciated